# BIM360 Data Management API returns a different name (odd) for a folder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

When querying a BIM360 Docs project using the topFolders api : https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-project_id-topFolders-GET/ the attributes.name value returned was the same as Display name. Now, the name is in the format of group-######## (eg, group-11654361).

Do you know what a BIM360 docs user is doing to make this change in the Forge Data? I would really like to understand what the user did to change the json.

Comment: Can you please share the ProjectId? And please add the JSON payload and a screenshot of BIM360 with the project/folder that is not working as expected?

Comment: I'm not sure I can get that requested data. I'll try to see if we have a reproducible case internally